# Element Being Positioned Outside an Element

Tags: css, html, position

I am trying to make an HTML DOM slideshow creator, that inserts text, images, etc. into slides for presentations. The main browsers in mind are the Nintendo DSi and 3DS browsers, but I would like functionality with computers as well, meaning that I AM using CSS percentages.

But here's the catch: An HTML span element has a relative positioning of top 100% and left:90%.

The left position is fine--the top position is not...I don't understand why, but the span is being displayed COMPLETELY outside the element from the top positioning.

Check this out for yourself [here](http://nos.heliohost.org/NintendOS%20Office/create_show.php).

"Slide 1" is supposed to be ABOVE the bottom border for the light gray div I have. Why is this outside when the positioning should be relative to that div?

I've always been so confused with CSS positioning...Could someone please figure this out for me? This is getting frustrating. By the way, what your looking for is "Slide 1" outside the HTML div.

Answer (score 0):

It is "being displayed COMPLETELY outside the element" precisely because of the `top: 100%`. That is telling it to move the `span` 100% the height of the container, which of course since it started at the top of the container, it puts it just past the bottom of the container. Note that `relative` positioning is not done "relative to that div" as you stated, it is actually relative to that `span` ([you may want to do some reading on that](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comparison)). However, when using percentage offsets, it does calculate its offsets in relation to the size of the container.

Since your `div.slide` container is itself `position:relative`, then I believe what you want is to set your `span` to `position:absolute` and instead of doing a `top` positioning, do a `bottom: 0` which will place it directly on the bottom of the `div` you are trying to place it on the bottom of. You can keep your `left: 90%`.